# Spring MVC and Thymeleaf Button disabled update

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have two buttons in my form(first and second). Now, I want to update the disable function of my second button when I click the first one.

```
<form action="updateButton" method="post" id="something">
        <h1 th:text="${application.text}"></h1>
        <button type="submit" name="first">First</button>
        <button type="submit" name="second" th:disabled="${model.disabled}">Second</button>
    </form>
```

**My Controller:**

```
private Boolean disabled = false;

public Boolean getDisabled() {
    return disabled;
}

public void setDisabled(Boolean disabled) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
}
```

Is there a way to bind the boolean variable with my second button, so that the button enables/disables onclick at the first button? I know I have to write a method with PostMapping("updateButton"). But I don't know how to bind the variable.

Comment: you can try `js` to do that

Answer (score 6):

This implementation should be done with `Javascript` and not `Thymeleaf`.

It has not sense do it with Thymeleaf and reload the page for such thing.

But if you are too much interested in it you could do it adding an action url to the form with something liket this:

```
<form action="updateButton" method="get" id="something" action="/ws">
        <h1 th:text="${application.text}"></h1>
        <button type="submit" name="first">First</button>
        <button type="submit" name="second" th:disabled="${model.disabled}">Second</button>
</form>
```

Then you would need a Web service in your controller which handles this situation and redirects to the `mapping view` putting an attribute to true.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ws")
public ModelAndView disable(@RequestParam("second") String second, Model model) {
    Model model = new Model();        
    model.addAttribute("disableSecondButton", true);

    return "yourview";
}
```

Finally add the conditional:

```
<div th:switch="${disableSecondButton}"> 
  <button type="submit" name="second" th:case="'true'" disabled>Second</button>
  <button type="submit" name="second" th:case="*">Second</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of resolving this issue by considering the above. Adding to model will also work. No need for variable creation. Also, please have a look at the below options.

### Using the model Attribute

```
@GetMapping("/users/edit/{id}")
public String example1(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("users", service.readUserById(id));
    model.addAttribute("disabled", true);
    return "editUsers";
}
```

### Use ModelMap

If you're adding multiple times on different method calls

```
@GetMapping("/users/edit/{id}")
public String example2(@PathVariable("id") Long id, ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.put("users", service.readUserById(id));
    modelMap.put("disabled", true);
    return "editUsers";
}
```

If you're directly referring the model or entity object, have a field declared disabled and make that variable transient so it will not be picked by hibernate.

#### Model

```
public User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    // others eliminated
    
    @Transient
    private boolean disabled = true;
    
    // getter and setter are eliminated
}
```

#### Controller

```
@GetMapping("/users/edit/{id}")
public String example(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    User user = service.readUserById(id);
    user.setDisabled(false);
    model.addAttribute("users", service.readUserById(id));
    return "editUsers";
}
```

Same follows for command object and its conversion.

#### In UI

For example one and two

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="userID" th:disabled="${user.disabled}"
    th:field="*{id}" placeholder="Enter User Id"/>
```

For example three

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="userID" th:disabled="*{user.disabled}"
    th:field="*{id}" placeholder="Enter User Id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public ModelAndView showMain(ModelAndView mav) {
    Model model = new Model();        
    model.setDissetDisabled(true);

    mav.addObject("model", model);
    mav.setViewName("/test/yourViewName");

    return mav;
}
```

**html**

```
<div th:if="${model.disabled}">
     // put your second button
     <input type="button" value="Second" /> 
<div>
```

**model**

```
public class Model {

    private Boolean disabled;

    public Boolean getDisabled() {
        return disabled;
    }

    public void setDisabled(Boolean disabled) {
        this.disabled = disabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. First of all i havent a model object in my class. I think you ment to put the boolean variable into the addObject-method. But then he says property or field 'disabled' cannot be found on null.

Comment: make model for you. check post :)